# Import page component and getServerSideProps from index.ts

Tags: node.js, import, next.js, export

The structure of my files is as follow:

```
pages/
├── api/
├── login/
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── login.tsx
```

login.tsx:

```
export const LoginPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>content.....</div>
  )
}
```

index.ts:

```
export const getServeSideProps = async () => ({
    props: {
      props:'prop'
    },
  }
)

import { LoginPage } from './login'

export default LoginPage
```

With this structure the proprs from `getServeSideProps` are avaialbe in the LoginPage. But I would like to have `getServeSideProps` as a separate file and just import it `index.ts`.

So this is how I would like to structure my files:

login.tsx:

```
export const LoginPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>content.....</div>
  )
}
```

getServeSideProps.ts:

```
export const getServeSideProps = async () => ({
    props: {
      props:'prop'
    },
  }
)
```

index.ts:

```
import { getServeSideProps } from './getServeSideProps'
import { LoginPage } from './login'

export default LoginPage
```

Comment: What's the question here? Keep it in a file outside pages directory, import it and then re-export it from index. Also it should be `getServerSideProps`. You're missing `r`. And, since you've put `login.tsx` inside the pages itself, it'll be directly accessible under `/login/login`. Better remove it from pages, and create a separate directory for components.

Comment: The question is how do I get ```getServerSideProps``` to be called by having it in a separate file and importing it in index.ts?

Comment: Just export `getServerSideProps` again in your `index.ts` file: `export { getServerSideProps } from './getServerSideProps'`.

Comment: Also, to reiterate what was said before, you should only have page components inside your `pages` folder. Move everything that's not a page to a separate folder.